# Where can you see current Bitcoin miners signalling SegWit2x?

Tags: segwit2x

Hi I know you can view current miners signalling 'intent' to implement SegWit2x on coindance https://coin.dance/blocks . But is there a live website that show miners actually signalling SegWit2x?

Answer (score 8):

Blocks signalling for the SegWit2x, i.e. the New York Agreement segwit activation (BIP91), are setting bit4. This shows up as a '1' in the second to last position of the version field. Blocks signalling readiness for BIP141, i.e. regular segwit activation, do so on bit1 which shows up as '2' in the last position of the version field. It is also possible to signal readiness for both:

```
  20000010              20000002               20000012
        ↑                      ↑                     ↑↑
       bit4                   bit1                   bit4 and bit1
```

[**xbt.eu**](https://xbt.eu) is explicitly tracking the bit4 signalling already, but you can see the version field for blocks on most block explorers, and sites that track such information such as [coin.dance](https://coin.dance).

Note: Bit 4 refers to `1<<4` and is thus the fifth bit from the back because the first is Bit 0. ;)

Comment: Why is bit 28 set to 1?

Comment: @sanket1729: I've amended my answer to answer your question.

Comment: I meant bit 28 in sense you were talking 1<<28. Referring to the 2 at the start of each number. **2**0000010. Or should this be asked as a new question?

Comment: @sanket1729: Before BIP9, the version field was supposed to be linearly counted up for protocol upgrades. We got up to version 2. ;)

Comment: Quick one; Is the % above based on (hash rate signalling)/(total current hash rate)?

Comment: @Josh: Hash rate signalling is measured as `blocks signalling/total blocks`. I'm confused, though, in that my answer doesn't mention percentages.

Comment: Thanks @Murch I get it. Sorry meant percentages on websites which would obviously be the ratio you just mentioned.

Comment: Forgive my ignorance, but why does xbt.eu show BIP91 and NYA separately, if they are one and the same?

Comment: @Robin: "NYA" was a string miners put into the coinbase transaction in order to communicate intent to support SegWit2x. BIP91 is an actual versionbits deployment of a softfork by setting a bit in the versionfield.

Comment: @Murch Thank you! I think the way the data was presented on that site threw me a little, but with your explanation it makes complete sense now :)

Answer (score 3):

You can see that information here (SegWit2x is BIP91): https://www.xbt.eu/

Answer (score 1):

[BTC.com](https://btc.com/) will show you what miners are signalling for in their coinbase. In their [pools page](https://btc.com/stats/pool), you can see recent blocks for each pool too, so that you can see when pools start/stop signalling for different proposals.

Answer (score 0):

I found a live update here of miners signalling for SegWit2x. At time of writing Bitmain has just started signalling bringing SegWit2x at 64% support. (This is what was meant by signalling vs intent)

http://www.coindesk.com/bitcoin-scaling-watch-news-guides-navigate-coming-clash-code/

Comment: and here https://blockchain.info/charts/nya-support